# How to change the first line only on certain files in a folder using sed

Tags: sed, windows

I'm doing this on Windows Vista 32 bit version.
I have 2 folders on my desktop : folder_a (with sed.exe) and folder_b with these files :

```
sand.txt
tree.txt
chair.txt
xyz-fork.txt
xyz-spoon.txt
```

If I run a batch file with this string:

```
call "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_a\sed.exe" -i "1c table-zeta" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\*xyz*.txt
```

I'm able to change the first line of those files whose filename contains xyz.

Now what I want to do is changing the first line of those files whose filename **DOES NOT** contain xyz
In this case only sand.txt, tree.txt and chair.txt will be modified.

I've heard about using ! to negate but I don't know how.

Comment: is that cygwin? or the ubuntu-on-windows thing?

Comment: What about using "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\file*.txt"?

Comment: You're right but maybe i've made the wrong example. what if the file list is something like this ?

Comment: sand.txt
tree.txt
chair.txt
xyz-fork.txt
xyz-spoon.txt

Comment: `sed` plays no part in what files get passed to it - that's up to the shell in which you are executing it. In your case, that appears to be the Windows `cmd` shell - so you question is off-topic for U&L IMHO. You will likely find some related questions on [su] e.g. [Excluding files of particular extension using DIR command on windows command line](http://superuser.com/questions/383641/excluding-files-of-particular-extension-using-dir-command-on-windows-command-lin)

Comment: I'm not an expert but i'm not using windows cmd.I created a .bat file with that string which recalls sed.exe placed in folder_a. You said that "sed" plays no part in what files get passed, but if i use sed and the command <<*xyz*.txt>> i'm able to modify only those files containing xyz in their filename. It has to be a way to modify files whose filename doesn't contain xyz but i have no idea !